# Updating a local SAS table from a CSV file

Tags: csv, import, sas

3 and have a table which I need to update. From my understanding, you can do something like the following:

```
data new_table;
  update old_table update_table;
  by some_key;
run;
```

My issue (well I have a few...) is that I'm importing the "update_table" from a CSV file and the formats aren't matching the "old_table", so the update fails.

I've tried creating the "update_table" from the "old_table" using proc sql create table with zero observations, which created the correct types/formats, but then I was unable to insert data into it without replacing it.

The other major issue I have is that there are a large number of columns (480), and custom formats, and I've run up against a 6000 character limit for the script.

I'm very new to SAS and any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a data step to read in your CSV. There are lots of papers out there explaining how to do this, so I won't cover it here.  This will allow you to specify the format (numeric/character) for each field.  The nice thing here is you already know what formats they need to be in (from your existing dataset), so you can create this read in fairly easily.

Let's say your data is so:

```
data have;
informat x date9.;
input x y z $;
datalines;
10JAN2010 1 Base
11JAN2010 4 City
12JAN2010 8 State
;;;;
run;
```

Now, if you have a CSV of the same format, you can read it in by generating the input code from the above dataset. You can use `PROC CONTENTS` to do this, or you can generate it by using `dictionary.tables` which has the same information as `PROC CONTENTS`.

```
proc sql;
  select catx(' ',name,ifc(type='char', '$' ,' '))into :inputlist 
   separated by ' '
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE';
  select catx(' ',name,informat) into :informatlist separated by ' '
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE'
   and not missing(informat);
quit;
```

The above are two examples; they may or may not be sufficient for your particular needs.

Then you use them like so:

```
data want;
infile datalines dlm=',';
informat &informatlist.;
input &inputlist.;
datalines;
13JAN2010,9,REGION
;;;;
run;
```

(obviously you would use your CSV file instead of datalines, just used here as example).

The point is you can write the data step code using the metadata from your original dataset.

Comment: Thanks Joe. The data step using the metadata is what I think I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this today, so I made a macro out of it:  https://core.sasjs.io/mp__csv2ds_8sas.html

It doesn't wrap the input statement so it may break with a large number of columns if you have batch line length limits.  If anyone would like me to fix that, just raise an issue:  https://github.com/sasjs/core/issues/new